# Displaying random images on websites

Tags: html

For a website is it possible to put all the images in a pool and every time a page is opened or refreshed it will draw 3 different images?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can do this either via a client language (e.g. javascript) or a server one (e.g. php using eventually a mysql database). It all depends on your needs.

Comment: Everything is possible... the real question is: [have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (Please read the link provided)

Comment: First of all I am a newbie, so thank you for all the minuses. I just want to learn. I guess my question should be I have three images on each webpage of my site and each image should display a different image when visited upon or refreshed. What programming language would be best suited for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't randomized image with html , you have to use java script or css5 try this

```
          window.onload = choosePic;

      var myPix = new Array("images/lion.jpg","images/tiger.jpg","images/bear.jpg");

       function choosePic() {
 randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * myPix.length));
  document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
                }
```